# Can I bind to multiple consumer groups with Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am writing an application that will process event messages (posted to the topic `file-upload-completed`). I have multiple endpoints that should consume these messages (`metadata-reader` and `quota-checker`), and for pragmatic reasons I would like to deploy these endpoints together in an aggregated package.

With Spring Cloud Stream, I could use `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.file-upload-completed.group=metadata-reader` to set the consumer group for the first endpoint; I would also like to process messages under the `quota-check` group, but the property-based configuration only permits one consumer group binding per message queue.

Is there a way to configure Spring Cloud Stream so that I can bind to a single message queue under multiple consumer groups in the same application?

Answer (score 4):

> but the property-based configuration only permits one consumer group binding per message queue.

by per message queue, do you mean, per-binding?

Also, when you specify the property `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.file-upload-completed.group=metadata-reader`, the `file-upload-completed` here means the bound target name (ex: the channel name) and you can define as many number of channels and their bindings with the specific consumer group that bound to a specific destination (topic: `file-upload-completed`)

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.mychannel1.destination=file-upload-completed
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.mychannel1.group=metadata-reader

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.mychannel2.destination=file-upload-completed
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.mychannel2.group=metadata-reader
```

With the above configuration, you can perform operations such as join etc., something like this:

```
@StreamListener
 public void receive(@Input(Processor.INPUT) SubscribableChannel input1, 
 @Input("mychannel2") SubscribableChannel input2) {
// perform operations (join etc.,)
}
```

Comment: I want multiple distinct bindings to the same channel, so that delivery to multiple endpoints within an aggregate deployment package is tracked independently by the message broker.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `consumer group` means [singleton consumer in cluster](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#consumer-groups). If both your endpoints are in the same app, no reason to extract new consumer group. You can just [`publish-subscribe`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-implementations-publishsubscribechannel) an incoming message to all your endpoints internally.

Comment: They are semantically distinct, and in the future I am wanting to be able to break them apart. They aren't "in the same app" as far as workflow is concerned, I am simply wanting to deploy multiple beans side-by-side in the same container. This is similar to the "aggregate" feature already provided, but with a different use case.